# Select literals as table data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

Consider table Address , with fields Country, State, and other data fields. I want to get all the records except for those with Country,State combination  as (US, IL), (US,LA), (IND,DEL)

The query goes like

```
Select * from Address a 
where not exists 
(
   select Country,State 
   (select 'US' as Country, 'IL' as State 
     union
   select 'US' as Country, 'LA' as State 
     union
    select 'IND' as Country, 'DEL' as State 
  ) e
 where e.Country != a.Country and e.State != a.state
)
```

How can it be easily achieved (to replace coutry,state combination of union with simple subquery)? As total data is not very large, i am least bothered about performance for now.

---

I know i can create table variable, add all literal combination there using insert into syntax, and use table variable for not exists, but i feel it is overkill for small requirement (not exists on 2 variables).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will add example to illustrate the issue better

Comment: It sounds to me like you are asking how to A) create dynamic SQL, or B) write more optimal SQL in this specific case -- could use better description of the problem

Comment: This just seems confusing that you have a table with the Country and State columns populated and you are doing a not exists to select data from it. Whats wrong with "SELECT * FROM Address WHERE Country = @Country and State = @State" ?

Comment: Your example has 3 country/state pairs. Is 3 a fixed number. How are you getting 3 pairs -- specifically via passed parameter or as a query result?

Comment: @Gary, it is hard coded, the examples are for illustration. Table is not so simple, pairs are 10 to 15. (they keep on changing, but that is ok for me)

Comment: Based on what you say, I think using a table var is actually a good solution. Simple to maintain, and understand. I often use table vars for solutions similar to your case.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like your query tried to do this:

```
select * 
from Address a 
where not exists (
                 select *
                 from (
                      select 'US' as Country, 'IL' as State union all
                      select 'US' as Country, 'LA' as State union all
                      select 'IND' as Country, 'DEL' as State 
                      ) e
                 where e.Country = a.Country and 
                       e.State = a.State
                 )
```

Or you could not use a derived table and still get the same result

```
select *
from Address as a
where not (
          a.Country = 'US' and a.State = 'IL' or
          a.Country = 'US' and a.State = 'LA' or
          a.Country = 'IND' and a.State = 'DEL'
          )
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the values directly in the query:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Table as Table ( Country VarChar(6), State VarChar(6), Foo VarChar(6) );
insert into @Table ( Country, State, Foo ) values
  ( 'US', 'IL', 'one' ), ( 'XX', 'LA', 'two' ), ( 'IND', 'XXX', 'three' ), ( 'IND', 'DEL', 'four' );

select * from @Table;

-- Demonstrate excluding specific combinations.
select T.*
  from @Table as T left outer join
    ( values ( 'US', 'IL' ), ( 'US', 'LA' ), ( 'IND', 'DEL' ) ) as Exclude( Country, State )
    on T.Country = Exclude.Country and T.State = Exclude.State
  where Exclude.Country is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
select * 
from Address a 
left outer join
    ( select 'US' as Country, 'IL' as State 
        union select 'US', 'LA'  
        union select 'IND', 'DEL'  ) as n
    on a.Country = n.Country and a.State = n.State
  where n.Country is NULL;
```